# A probability concerning the maximum and minimum of a simple random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, maxima-minima, random-walk

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. such that $\mathbb P(X_i = 1 )=\mathbb P(X_i=-1) =\frac1 2$. Let $a\in \{1,2,....\}$, now define the random walk, $S_0=a$ and
$$S_n = a+\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
Now define the maximum and minimum of the random walk until time index $n$ as follows,
$$M_n := \sup_{0\leq j \leq n } S_j,\ \ \ \ m_n:=\inf_{0\leq j\leq n} S_j$$
Let $b\in\mathbb N \backslash \{0\}$ and define $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $0<a,b<k$.

> **My question: how can I find**
> $$\mathbb P(S_n=b, m_n\leq 0, M_n\geq k)$$

---

**Trials.** I wanted to use the reflection principle, so I first considered the cases where the maximum occurred first and where the minimum occured first. I know that both boil down to the same thing, by the duality theorem. So we can as well consider
$$u:=\mathbb P(S_n=b, m_n\leq 0, M_n\geq k, \text{ minimum occurred first})$$
See [Random walk example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB75p.png) for the visualization of random walk I had in mind. So, I start with the blue path. It should cross zero, so I reflected there and got the red path.  Then next I should cross the level $-k$, but when I get there I reflect again to get the green path. I finnally conclude
$$u=\mathbb P(S_n = b-2k)$$

The problem is that I think that this is wrong. Because this finally lead to
$$\mathbb P(S_n=b, m_n\leq 0, M_n\geq k)> \mathbb P(S_n=b,  M_n\geq k)$$
which is completely nonsense. Sorry I skipped the calculations, but this is the reason I think it is wrong.

If people really want the calculations for $\mathbb P(S_n=b,  M_n\geq k)$ then I can also write it, but I'm afraid it is too much.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb P(X_i = 1 )=\mathbb P(X_i=-1) =\frac1 2$?

Comment: @d.k.o. Sorry was a mistake, should be $-1$, i edited

Answer (score 1):

This is quite tricky! Let

- $E_{u,d}$ be the set of paths from $a$ to $b$ for which at some point $S_i= k$, and at some *later* point $S_j= 0$, where $j> i$.
- $E_{d,u}$ be the paths which which hit zero, and then at some later point hit $k$.

You want to count
$$
|E_{u,d}\cup E_{d,u}|
$$
First, start by counting $|E_{u,d}|$. You do this by reflecting at the first time the path hits $k$. Since the original path hit zero at some point after this, the reflected path will hit $2k$ at some point after that, so you reflect again at the first after the first reflection point the path hits $2k$. The result is a path from $0$ to $b+4k$. There are $\binom{n}{\frac12(n+4k+b-a)}$ such paths.

Similarly, to count $|E_{d,u}|$, we reflect at the first time the path hits zero, and the the first time after that the reflected path hits $-k$. The result is a path from $a$ to $b-2k$.

However, we cannot just add $|E_{u,d}|+|E_{d,u}|$ to get the size of the union $|E_{u,d}\cup E_{d,u}|$. There are overlaps. Specifically, let

- $E_{u,d,u}$ be the set of paths which hit $k$, then at a later point hit $0$, then at a later point hit $k$.
- $E_{d,u,d}$ be the set of paths which hit $0$, then at a later point hit $k$, then at a later point hit $0$.

The paths in $E_{u,d,u}$ have been counted twice in the sum $|E_{u,d}|+|E_{d,u}|$, so they need to be subtracted out. You can count $|E_{u,d,u}|$ by applying the reflection principle twice. Same goes for $|E_{d,u,d}|$. The current sum is 
$$
|E_{u,d}|+|E_{d,u}|-|E_{u,d,u}|-|E_{d,u,d}|
$$
However, we are still not done. Defining $E_{u,d,u,d}$ similarly, paths in $E_{u,d,u,d}$ were counted twice in $|E_{u,d}|+|E_{d,u}|$, but then subtracted out twice in $-|E_{u,d,u}|-|E_{d,u,d}|$, so they need to be added back in.

It turns out that the pattern continues on exactly like this. Letting $E_i=|E_{u,d,u,\dots}|$, with $i$ symbols in the subscript, and letting $F_i=|E_{d,u,d,\dots}|$ with $i$ symbols, the final answer is
$$
\sum_{i=2}^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor+1} (-1)^{i}\Big(|E_i|+|F_i|\Big)
$$
You can write $|F_i|$ and $|E_i|$ as a certain binomial coefficient by applying the reflection principle $i$ times, but I leave this part to you as keeping track of all those reflections is tedious.